# jQuery TokenInput must be required

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Good day,

I am having problem with jQuery TokenInput. I don't know if this question was asked already. But I need to make it required/ have 1 value at least, without using jquery validtor plugins.

Help please. Thanks!

Comment: are you using any jquery plugin for validations?

Comment: No sir. No jquery validator plugins

Comment: what you can do is, as user select any item from dropdown - store that value in hidden input tag also..and while submitting you can check if hidden is null display error message..else successfully submit page